# Python Multithread/process combination of Json and Python?

Tags: python, json, multithreading, dictionary, multiprocessing

So currently im trying to get a function right. Basically im trying to do a multiple (Concurrently) thread that takes information from a Json file into the program and then for every thread it should use each json object and then execute the code with those information.

*What I have done so far - This code is only for Multiprocess which indeed works.:*

```
#Read json File
with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    profiles_string = json.load(json_data)

def get_individual_profiles(config):
    top_layer = config.get('Profiles')
    if top_layer:
        top_level_keys = ['profile_{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(top_layer))]
        print(top_level_keys)
        return [(key, top_layer.get(key)) for key in top_level_keys]
    return []

def stringify(key, next_layer):
    return [
        ' '.join(key.capitalize().split('_')),
        next_layer.get('Name'),
        next_layer.get('Last_Name'),
        next_layer.get('Email'),
        next_layer.get('Phone')
        #etc etc...
        ]

    config = profiles_string
profiles = get_individual_profiles(config)

pool = ThreadPool()

# Launch a process for each item
threads = [pool.apply_async(stringify, tuple(item)) for item in profiles]


# get() the results as each finishes
results = [res.get() for res in threads]
print('threaded results:')
for item in results:
    print(item)
```

**Output:**

```
threaded results:
['Profile 0', 'Thrill', 'Ofit', 'Stack@hotmail.com', '123 412 123']

['Profile 1', 'Hellow', 'World', 'Stac321k@hotmail.com', '543 412 312']
```

Which is great. But the **issues is:**

That whenever I want to etc use those info

**EXEMPLE**

```
def checkoutNames(NameUrl, nameID):
payload = {
        "shared": {
            "challenge": {
              "Name": item["Name"],
              "Last_Name": item["Last_Name"],
              "Email": item["Email"],
              "Phone": item["Phone"],
```

Is that it wont recognize those attributes but what I need to do is that I need to call them by item[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNiUw.jpg).. item[2] etc from that order that is from `def stringify(key, next_layer):` which I don't know by now how to make it so I don't need to do it.

The other problem is that whenever we say ETC that I use item[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNiUw.jpg) in the code. Then it will only use the last thread and skip the rest. So if I do

```
print(item[1])
```

Then the only output that will come is the last one which is *Hello*

So the problems I need to get solved:

**1. To make each thread to execute concurrently and execute the code with those information**

**2. Make a fix so I don't need to use item[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNiUw.jpg) but to use instead item['Name'].**

So the question is, is this possible and what is the ideas about this?

**EDIT - This is the code i'm currently having with only one Json profile and that is working fine with just one profile. This is WITHOUT multiprocessing**

Json file

```
      {
    "Profiles": {
        "profile_0": {
            "Url": "Myownwebsite.se",
            "My-Note": "Helloworld",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "1234543",
            "postal_code": "54123",
            "given_name": "World",
            "Last_name": "Hellow",
            "street_address": "helloworld 123",
            "city": "Stockholm",
            "country": "Sweden",
            "phone": "123456789",
            "Color": "Red",
            "house_number": "123",
            "year": "2017"
        },
        "profile_1": {
            "Url": "Myasdwfaesite.se",
            "My-Note": "aasfase",
            "Email": "fasfsef@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "5634543",
            "postal_code": "123445",
            "given_name": "Balling",
            "Last_name": "Calling",
            "street_address": "qwertr 123",
            "city": "London",
            "country": "UK",
            "phone": "65412331",
            "Color": "Blue",
            "house_number": "321",
            "year": "2018"
        }

        #Profile_2 etc etc
    }
}
```

**Code**

```
    with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

NameUrl = config["Url"]

myNote = config["My-Note"]

def checkoutNames(NameUrl, nameID):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......
    headers = {
        'Referer': '',
        'Content-Type': ''
    }
    payload = {
        "shared": {
            "challenge": {
                "email": config["Email"],
                "PersonNumber": config["PersonNumber"],
                "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
                "given_name": config["Name"],
                "Last_name": config["LastName"],
                "street_address": config["Address"],
                "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
                "city": config["City"],
                "country": config["Country"],
                "email": config["Email"],
                "phone": config["Phone"],
            }

def checkoutNotes(NamesUrl, NamesPost):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': NameUrl,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
    payloadInfo = {
        "Information": {
            "Color": config["Color"],
            "house_number": config["houseNumber"],
            "year": config["Year"]
      }
    }    
def wipe():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def main():
    time.sleep(1)

    FindName(myNote)

if _name_ == '_main_':
    try: {
        main()
    }
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        wipe()
```

**EDIT**

I just wanted to print out what Yaroslav code gives for output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You making list and expexcting it to work like dictionary. If order matters - use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from collections. By the way, you could load you json using something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
.... # your previous code
profiles_string = json.load(json_data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Try with this code:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import threading
from time import sleep
import random

with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
  config = json.loads(json_data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)


def stringify(key, next_layer):
  sleep(random.random()) # work emulation
  # `key` is profile name (profile_0, profile_1 etc)
  # `next_layer` is profile payload as OrderedDict:
  # {
  #    "Url": "Myasdwfaesite.se",
  #    "My-Note": "aasfase",
  #    "Email": "fasfsef@gmail.com",
  #    "PersonNumber": "5634543",
  #    "postal_code": "123445",
  #    "given_name": "Balling",
  #    "Last_name": "Calling",
  #    "street_address": "qwertr 123",
  #    "city": "London",
  #    "country": "UK",
  #    "phone": "65412331",
  #    "Color": "Blue",
  #    "house_number": "321",
  #    "year": "2018"
  #}

  # this print statement just for illustartion
  print(threading.current_thread().name, key)
  return { key: next_layer }  # still ordered

# how much workers should be started
profiles_number = len(config.get('Profiles', {}).items())

pool = ThreadPool(profiles_number)

# Launch a thread for each item and get() the results as each finishes
# `starmap_async` returns result object when all tasks are finished, so
# single get is called. Result object in thios case behave like list
results = pool.starmap_async(stringify, config.get('Profiles', {}).items()).get()

print('threaded results:')
for i in results:
    print(i, end='\n***\n')  # result separator when printed
```

Comment: Thank you @Yaroslav! However when I tried this. It did not work. What I get for print is [None, None]. What could cause that issue? Maybe because there isn't anything on ```print(item)```? also if I want to print out etc. Url from the thread. Wouldnt in that case print(config['Url']) done it?

Comment: @WeInThis, sorry, double `return` statement was fault. Try edited code, should be ok

Comment: Hey again! Ok so it worked. However I found another issue. So whats happening now is that it just loads into one thread and inside that thread there is the whole print of all the objects including all the profiles. I don't think it should act like that. However also. How would it be if I exemple want to grab out the URL. Etc ```Url = "Grab url from profile_0" and print(Url)``` ?

Comment: @WeInThis i've added some comments to show what's happening in there

Comment: Oh you are right. It does now show the ````Thread-1 for profile_0 and Thread-2 for profile_1```` which means it does work. You can see the picture I just added to see the output.

 Okey. So in that case that means it does give the right attributes. I have been trying to figure out now. Like I said before I do have ``` NameUrl = config["Url"]
myNote = config["My-Note"] ``` inside my code and im just curious how I can in that case use those from the stringify to the attributes that iam wanting to give etc in payload ?

Comment: @WeInThis in my example all your profile payload is loaded as ordered dictionary ( `next_layer` variable ), so you can access it's values with `next_layer["My-Note"]` inside of `stringify` function.

Comment: Yes! I know about that but what if I exempel want to use it outside the function. Like in the code above the picture I just edit. there is exemple ```def checkoutNotes(NamesUrl, NamesPost):``` that has ```PayloadInfo```. How can I in that case transfer it from your code (From stringify) to the code where I want to get it located (Payload) ?

Comment: @WeInThis that's another question and, besides, do you want me to code all script for you? I've allready helped you solving both of your problems, listed in your post and from now you should at least try to adopt the answer to your project. Also i reccomend you to search over stackoverflow for questions about threading

Comment: Thank you Yaroslav! I really appreciate it and I will mark this as answer. Thank you very much and have a nice and awesome Saturday! :)